# python: logging output from external API to logger module

Tags: python, logging, stdout

I am python beginner. My python script logs output to a file (say example.log) using the basic python logging module. However, my python script also makes some 3rd party API calls (for example, parse_the_file) over which I don't have any control. I want to capture the output (usually on console) produced by the API into my example.log. The following example code works partially but the problem is that the contents get overwritten as soon as I start logging output of the API into my log file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import logging
import sys
import os
from common_lib import *     # import additional modules

logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log', filemode='w', level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

logging.debug('This is a log message.') # message goes to log file.

sys.stdout = open('example.log','a')
metadata_func=parse_the_file('/opt/metadata.txt') # output goes to log file but OVERWRITES the content
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
logging.debug('This is a second log message.') # message goes to log file.
```

I know there have been post suggesting to similar question on this site but I haven't a workaround/solution for this problem that will work in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
log_file = open('example.log', 'a')
logging.basicConfig(stream=log_file, level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug("Test")
sys.stdout = log_file
sys.stderr = log_file
stdout_fd = os.dup(1)
stderr_fd = os.dup(2)
os.dup2(log_file.fileno(), 1)
os.dup2(log_file.fileno(), 2)

os.system("echo foo")

os.dup2(stdout_fd, 1)
os.dup2(stderr_fd, 2)
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__
```

However, this will not format it accordingly. If you want that, you can try something like http://plumberjack.blogspot.com/2009/09/how-to-treat-logger-like-output-stream.html

Comment: I just corrected my post. I was using 'a' in the open call. In short, using 'a' still overwrites the content because I think the logging mechanism is not aware that the file pointer has moved because of the open call. This is my best guess.

Comment: Yeah, I was rather stupid. I updated it with something that should work.

Comment: Thanks! That works for me. I didn't know there was a stream option for logging.basicConfig.

Comment: OK, I hit a snag...I was under impression that sys.stdout = log_file will work for anything that follows it. For example, I just realize that the output is not logged into the log file if I have a command like os.system(some_command_here) in my python script even though I am setting sys.stdout = log_file right before it. Any ideas?

Comment: I added code to get both stdout and stderr, and to work for non python output.

Comment: I found out that the following piece of code also works and is little shorter than your suggested solution for capturing output of system commands: status, output = commands.getstatusoutput(cmd),     log_file.write(output). Again, let me know if there are any caveats in doing it in this way...